# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Common_Registration' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: hibernate, jsp

***Common Registration Table***:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Common_Registration](
[Auto_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PK,
[CM_ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[type] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[Name_of_Institution] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[sub_type] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Document] [image] NULL,
[code] [image] NULL)
```

**Common_Login**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Common_Login](
[Login_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Pk,
[Auto_Id] [int] NOT NULL FK,
[username] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[type] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL)
```

**CommonRegistration Xml File**
**Auto Generated**

> It is to map CommonRegistration Data to database

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <!-- Generated 27 May, 2014 1:21:55 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0 -->
    <hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="PSPOJO.CommonRegistration" table="Common_Registration" schema="dbo"  
   catalog="PublicServices">
    <id name="autoId" type="int">
        <column name="Auto_Id" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="cmId" type="string">
        <column name="CM_ID" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="type" type="char">
        <column name="type" length="1" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="nameOfInstitution" type="string">
    <column name="Name_of_Institution" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="subType" type="string">
    <column name="sub_type" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="document" type="binary">
        <column name="Document" />
    </property>
    <property name="code" type="binary">
        <column name="code" />
    </property>
<set name="commonLogins" table="Common_Login" inverse="true" lazy="true" 
 fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="Auto_Id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="PSPOJO.CommonLogin" />
    </set>
</class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

***Common_Login***
**Auto Generated**

> It is to map CommonLoginData to database

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
  <!-- Generated 27 May, 2014 1:21:55 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0 -->
  <hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="PSPOJO.CommonLogin" table="Common_Login" schema="dbo"    
  catalog="PublicServices">
    <id name="loginId" type="int">
        <column name="Login_Id" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <timestamp name="timestamp" column="timestamp" />
    <many-to-one name="commonRegistration" class="PSPOJO.CommonRegistration" 
     fetch="select">
        <column name="Auto_Id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="username" type="string">
        <column name="username" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="password" type="string">
        <column name="password" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="type" type="char">
        <column name="type" length="1" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

**JAVA Code To save**
**Auto Generated**

```
    PSPOJO.CommonRegistration registration= new PSPOJO.CommonRegistration();
    try {
    registration.setCmId("1");
    registration.setType('M');
    registration.setNameOfInstitution(request.getParameter("name"));
    registration.setSubType(request.getParameter("subtype"));
    registration.setDocument(null);
    registration.setCode(null);
    mysession.save(registration);

    CommonLogin cl=new CommonLogin();
    cl.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
    cl.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
    cl.setType('M');    
    cl.setCommonRegistration(registration);
    registration.getCommonLogins().add(cl);

    mysession.save(cl);
    tx.commit();
    mysession.close();
```

> I got this error While Try to save

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Common_Registration' when         IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Comment: you should put complete exception trace here that would help. As per initial guessing it seems that you are setting value to identity column OR Hibernate is trying to save same object twice due to incorrect mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Your database table has an IDENTITY primary key ID and your Hibernate config use assigned.

- If you want your database to manage your ids automatically than replace:

with

```
<generator class="identity" />
```

or

```
<generator class="native" />
```

- If you want to manage your ids manually than remove the IDENTITY from your PK database table definitions.